# Index out of range for rectangle array?

Tags: c#, arrays, xna, collision-detection, rectangles

I have this problem with assigning individual rectangles to each value in an list. To try this out I first tried to give a rectangle to value 5.

```
snakeBodyRectangleArray[5] = new Rectangle((int)snakeBodyArray[5].X, (int)snakeBodyArray[5].Y, textureSnakeBody.Width, textureSnakeBody.Height);
// above is in update 
protected override void Initialize()
    {
        // TODO: Add your initialization logic here
        graphics.PreferredBackBufferWidth = 500;
        graphics.PreferredBackBufferHeight = 500;
        graphics.IsFullScreen = false;
        graphics.ApplyChanges();
        Window.Title = "Curvy Snake";

        snakeBodyArray = new List<Vector2>();
        snakeBodyRectangleArray = new List<Rectangle>();

        bodyTimer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(updateBodyPositions);
        bodyTimer.Interval = 120;
        bodyTimer.Enabled = true;

        base.Initialize();
    }
```

If you need more code, just ask.

thanks in advance

Comment: Arrays are zero-based. This means that the last element is at index 4, not 5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used

```
snakeBodyRectangleArray[bodyNumber] = new Rectangle((int)snakeBodyArray[bodyNumber].X, (int)snakeBodyArray[bodyNumber].Y, textureSnakeBody.Width, textureSnakeBody.Height);
```

and put it into a private void.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like that your array is a 5 element one or more precisely it's `number of element is <6` and you are trying to access an element which is out of the range of `snakeBodyRectangleArray`

Answer (score 0):

How is snakeBodyRectangleArray declared?
Does it have a size of 6 or higher?